# blueimp jQuery File Upload PHP MySQL database integration third textfield

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, file-upload, blueimp

I would like more than the two text fields 'title' and 'description' at upload, write to the DB. 
The DB is extended to the field 'datum'. 
The index.php - see below - file is expanded to include the new field. 
But it is written no entry.
Also the upload form has been extended by the field 'datum'.

```
protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
    $file->title = @$_REQUEST['title'][$index];
    $file->datum = @$_REQUEST['datum'][$index];
    $file->description = @$_REQUEST['description'][$index];
}

protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
        $index = null, $content_range = null) {
    $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
        $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
    );
    if (empty($file->error)) {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
            .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `datum`, `description`)'
            .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param(
            'sisss',
            $file->name,
            $file->size,
            $file->type,
            $file->title,
            $file->datum,
            $file->description
        );
        $query->execute();
        $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;
    }
    return $file;
}

protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
    parent::set_additional_file_properties($file);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
        $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `type`, `title`, `datum`, `description` FROM `'
            .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=?';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('s', $file->name);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result(
            $id,
            $type,
            $title,
            $datum,
            $description
        );
        while ($query->fetch()) {
            $file->id = $id;
            $file->type = $type;
            $file->title = $title;
            $file->datum = $datum;
            $file->description = $description;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->bind_param(
        'sisss',
        $file->name,
        $file->size,
        $file->type,
        $file->title,
        $file->datum,
        $file->description
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

add the missing one s in 'sisss'

```
$query->bind_param(
            'sissss',
            $file->name,
            $file->size,
            $file->type,
            $file->title,
            $file->datum,
            $file->description
        );
```

Comment: Could someone please enlighten me as to what 'sissss' is all about?? Googling it returns nothing

Comment: @Stuart it's [`types` parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) of `bind_param()`. It describes types of variables; `s`for string, `i` for integer. In this case, `$file->name` is string, `$file->size` is integer, `$file->type` is string, etc.